# How to make n nested for loops recursively?

Tags: java, recursion

I have a method that must do the following:

```
for (int a01 = 1; a01 <= 25; a01++) {
    for (int a02 = a01 + 1; a02 <= 25; a02++) {
        for (int a03 = a02 + 1; a03 <= 25; a03++) {
            ...
            System.out.println(a01 + "," + a02 + "," + ... + "," + a015);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to specify the number of nested for's (in the case above, I want 15 nested for's).
Is there a way to use recursive programming here?

Comment: Please, no. Don't do that.

Comment: Just create a method and let it call itself 15 times. That's a real recursive method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis care to explain why? ;-)

Comment: @om-nom-nom Unreadable, ununderstandable, ugly, bad design, full of bugs, anything bad you can think of.

Comment: In general, yes, you can do this recursively, and it can be "robust" and understandable.  (Note that recursive routines are often used for a tree search, which is effectively nested for statements.)  But note that there is geometric growth in the total number of iterations, and, nested 15 deep, the routine may never complete.  Go for it!  Even if you fail you'll learn something.

Comment: Note that the recursive routine just needs to accept the start index, the depth (decremented with each call), and whatever you need to address in the actual code.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I assume he does not like to code it that way. He likes to have a multi-dimensional for with a dimension of 25. Easy and clean using recursive programming - as he as asked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes. This can be performed by recursive programming.

I assume you do not like to WRITE DOWN these nested for's in source code - as in your example, because this is really ugly programming - like the commentors explain.

The following (pseudo Java-like) code illustrates it. I assume a fixed depth for the nesting. Then you actually like to loop over an integer vector of dimension depth.

```
int[] length = new int[depth];
int[] counters = new int[depth];
```

The array `counters` has to be initialised to 0 (`Arrays.fill(counters,0)`). The array `length` has to be initialised to the number of iterations for the respective for loop.

I assume that you like to perform a certain operation within the inner loop. I will call this
    `performOperation(int[] counters);`
- it depends on the multi-dimensional counter, i.e. the counters of the outer for's.

Then you can run the nested for loops by calling

```
nestedLoopOperation(counters, length, 0);
```

where

```
void nestedLoopOperation(int[] counters, int[] length, int level) {
    if(level == counters.length) performOperation(counters);
    else {
        for (counters[level] = 0; counters[level] < length[level]; counters[level]++) {
            nestedLoopOperation(counters, length, level + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

In your case your System.out.println() would be

```
performOperation(int[] counters) {
    String counterAsString = "";
    for (int level = 0; level < counters.length; level++) {
        counterAsString = counterAsString + counters[level];
        if (level < counters.length - 1) counterAsString = counterAsString + ",";
   }
   System.out.println(counterAsString);
}
```

Comment: Your inner function call is missing a parameter `length`.

Comment: Thank you. I started writing pseudo code, then did it Java, but did not check if it compiles - wrote directly here without IDE.

Comment: I tried out this code after converting it into Python.  So depth determines the size of the Vector, aka, how many nests in the loop, but what should the values for those Vectors be?  It seems like Length should always be depth (e.g. [3, 3, 3]), while Counter is just whatever it is in the loop (for [0, 1, 2] if you just want to start from 0 and stop after max -1)?

Comment: @ackmondual : No. Length is the length of a for loop. So if you have two nested loops `for(int i=0; i<13; i++) { for(int j=0; j<45; j++) { ... } }`then `depth=2` and `length = { 13, 45 }`.

Answer (score 1):

I created this program to show all the different possible combination of cards (non repeating). It uses recursive for loops. Maybe it can help you.

```
//I'm lazy, so yeah, I made this import...
import static java.lang.System.out;

class ListCombinations {

    //Array containing the values of the cards
    static Symbol[] cardValues = Symbol.values();

    //Array to represent the positions of the cards,
    //they will hold different card values as the program executes
    static Symbol[] positions = new Symbol[cardValues.length];

    //A simple counter to show the number of combinations
    static int counter = 1;

    /*Names of cards to combine, add as many as you want, but be careful, we're
    talking about factorials here, so 4 cards = 24 different combinations (4! = 24),
    but 8 cards = 40320 combinations and 13 cards = 6.23 billion combinations!*/
    enum Symbol {
        AofSpades, TwoofSpades, ThreeofSpades, FourofSpades
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //I send an argument of 0 because that is the first location which
        //we want to add value to. Every recursive call will then add +1 to the argument.
        combinations(0);
    }

    static void combinations(int locNumber) {

        /* I use a recursive (repeating itself) method, since nesting for loops inside
        * each other looks nasty and also requires one to know how many cards we will
        * combine. I used 4 cards so we could nest 4 for loops one after another, but
        * as I said, that's nasty programming. And if you add more cards, you would
        * need to nest more for loops. Using a recursive method looks better, and gives
        * you the freedom to combine as many cards as you want without changing code. */

        //Recursive for loop nesting to iterate through all possible card combinations
        for(int valueNumber = 0; valueNumber < cardValues.length; valueNumber++) {
            positions[locNumber] = cardValues[valueNumber];
            if (locNumber < (cardValues.length-1)) {
                combinations(locNumber + 1);
            }

            //This if statement grabs and displays card combinations in which no card value
            // is repeated in the current "positions" array. Since in a single deck,
            // there are no repeated cards. It also appends the combination count at the end.
            if (locNumber == (cardValues.length-1) && repeatedCards(positions)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cardValues.length; i++) {
                out.print(positions[i]);
                out.print(" ");
                }
                out.printf("%s", counter);
                counter++;
                out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean repeatedCards(Symbol[] cards) {

        /*Method used to check if any cards are repeated in the current "positions" array*/

        boolean booleanValue = true;

        for(int i = 0; i < cardValues.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < cardValues.length; j++) {
                if(i != j && cards[i] == cards[j]) {
                    booleanValue = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return booleanValue;
    }
}
```