# How to create as many nested loops as you want?

Tags: c++, recursion, nested-loops

I am trying to create a program that can take many numbers as I want in C++ language.
Then it find what operators can make the equation true and show all correct possible operation.
Example: If I put 3 5 15
Then it output  3x5 = 15
If I put 1 2 3 4 4
Then it outputs 1+2-3+4 =4

The following code is my written program:
The problem about it is that when I want to reduce the number of input or increase the number of input I need to add/reduce nested loops EVERYTIME. I want to know what is a more effective way of a more flexible nested loops or recursion method.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


char getOperator(int);
double operate(int, double, double);

int main() {
    double a, b, c, d, e, result;
    short noOfAnswers = 0;
    cout << "Input first 5 numbers to make it equal to another 1 number.\n" <<
    "I'll find what are the operators needed to make 2 sides of the equation equal.\n";
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e >> result;
    int noOfOperators = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i <= noOfOperators; i++) {
        double firstTwo = operate(i, a, b);
        for (int j = 0; j <= noOfOperators; j++) {
            double firstThree = operate(j, firstTwo, c);
            for (int k = 0; k <= noOfOperators; k++) {
                double firstFour = operate(k, firstThree, d);
                for (int l = 0; l <= noOfOperators; l++) {
                    double firstFive = operate(l, firstFour, e);
                    if (firstFive == result) {
                        cout << ++noOfAnswers << ')' << a << getOperator(i) << b << getOperator(j) << c
                        << getOperator(k) << d << getOperator(l) << e << '=' << result << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (noOfAnswers) cout << "I have found " << noOfAnswers << " solutions for this extremely hard problem for humanity \nin less than a second." << endl;
    else cout << "I cannot find any solutions to this problem.\n"
    <<"They're just a bunch of random numbers & That is UNSOLVABLE!" << endl;
    cout << "Do not doubt my judgment. I am always right!" << endl << "(Please note that all calculations are done from the left side first.)" << endl;
    return 0;
}

double operate(int iteration, double num1, double num2) {
    switch (iteration) {
        case 0: return num1+num2;
        case 1: return num1-num2;
        case 2: return num1*num2;
        case 3: return num1/num2;
        case 4: return pow(num1, num2);
        case 5: return fmod(num1, num2);
    }
    return 0;
}

char getOperator(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
        case 0: return '+';
        case 1: return '-';
        case 2: return 'x';
        case 3: return '/';
        case 4: return '^';
        case 5: return '%';
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

Comment: Try calling `operate()` from within `operate()`'s body itself and install a loop there. That would apply _recursion_ as you mentioned/asked for.

Comment: Store all input into a vector then iterate through the vector processing each element at a time, possibly using recursion as suggested by @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Don't. Use a queue or a stack or something and iterate over it.

Comment: What if I would like to apply this to other program too, I want to know how to loop this kind of thing by making a new recursive function or more efficient loop but not changing how the other functions work.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @off99555 As _@lLightness_ suggested use a [**stack**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) instead of recursion, that will make the code cleaner, and stacks always can be used to replace recursion for results. They're essentially the same, no performance drawbacks, better readable code,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, but I don't know what a stack or a queue is. Can you give me example of the code in c++ please?

Comment: @off99555 There are samples along the reference link I gave you (check the individual functions). Study these 1st.

Comment: Have you tried using a `std::vector` to hold your original numbers?

Comment: Please search the web for "tutorial data structures c++".  Data structures will make your programming job easier.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make n nested for loops recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406290/how-to-make-n-nested-for-loops-recursively)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use while() loops, cause you dont know when the loop terminates.

```
int main() {
    double numbers[] = {3,5,15};//consider storing the number as an array
    //the last element is the result
    double result;
    int arr_len = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(double);
    int i,j;

    while(1)
    {
          j = 0;
          while(j++ < 5)//over all operators
          {i = 0;
              result = numbers[0];//start with first element
              while(i < arrlen - 2)//over all numbers, exclude the result
              {
                 result = operate(j, result, numbers[++i]);
                 //something like this...this does not work correctly
                 //it might give you a hint in the right direction
                 if(result == numbers[arr_len - 1])//compare to last element
                     return 0;
              }  
          }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following may help:

```
// increment v where each value is a digit with maximal value maxSize
// so {0,1,2}, 3 lead to {0,2,0}
// return false on overflow.
bool increment(std::vector<int>& v, int maxSize)
{
    for (auto it = v.rbegin(); it != v.rend(); ++it) {
        ++*it;
        if (*it != maxSize) {
            return true;
        }
        *it = 0;
    }
    return false;
}

// display something like 1 + 2 * 3 = 9 // with the following meaning ((1 + 2) * 3) = 9
void display(const std::vector<double>& operands, const std::vector<int>& operators, double total)
{
    const char operators_string[] = "+-*/^%";

    std::cout << operands[0];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != operators.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << " " << operators_string[operators[i]] << " " << operands[i + 1];
    }
    std::cout << " = " << total << std::endl;
}

// Compute something like {1 2 3 4}, {+ * /} as (((1 + 2) * 3) / 4)
double compute(const std::vector<double>& operands, const std::vector<int>& operators)
{
    std::function<double(double, double)> fs[] = {
        [](double a, double b) { return a + b; },
        [](double a, double b) { return a - b; },
        [](double a, double b) { return a * b; },
        [](double a, double b) { return a / b; },
        [](double a, double b) { return pow(a, b); },
        [](double a, double b) { return fmod(a, b); },
    };

    double res = operands[0];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != operators.size(); ++i) {
        res = fs[operators[i]](res, operands[i + 1]);
    }
    return res;
}

void display_combinaison(const std::vector<double>& operands, double total)
{
    std::vector<int> operators(operands.size() - 1);

    do {
        if (compute(operands, operators) == total) {
            display(operands, operators, total);
        }
    } while (increment(operators, 6));
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/p9VSfr)