# Possible combination to form a given number

Tags: c++

How can I check that a given number can be formed by the positive integral combination of a given list of numbers.

For example, if the list of number is, 
    5 3 9

and

```
13
```

Then 13 can be formed by, 5*2 + 3. What is the possible algo for this? This is not a HW question. This was asked in an interview which I am preparing for. Please help!

Comment: One algorithm is: generate all possible permutations, and evaluate each one.

Comment: 2 is not in the list you gave.

Comment: It's fairly easy to recursively generate all combos of numbers and operators.  When one result matches, print it out.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to have anything to do with C++ (or any other programming language for that matter). Publish it on http://math.stackexchange.com, and then try to implement it according to the answer. If you have any concrete (programming) problems by then, publish it here.

Comment: @Oliver, how do I do that? Because numbers can be multiplied as well by any positive constant.

Comment: You'll also need to consider all variants of operators.

Comment: Following may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25943057/2684539

Answer (score 0):

I did this decades ago for combos of six numbers, (Countdown numbers game).  If the set of numbers is in a global array, all you need to pass down through each recursion is one integer index that describes how far along the array you have examined so far.