# Project R: Variable "depth" of for-loops; generalization

Tags: r, for-loop

Thank you for helping me out with this one. It's a problem that has been bothering me for quite a time now. I feel like I am so close to the answer, but not quite there yet.
Issue is the following:

Suppose I want to combine every possible combination of m-elements of n-vectors and store the result of, lets say, a multiplication. For the 2d-problem I need two interlaced for-loops:

```
dim2_Matrix <- matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=3)
for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:3){
  dim2_Matrix[i,j] <- i*j
  }
}
```

The inner loop will run through all 3 items, multiplying them with the first item of the outer loop. Once that procedure is done, i will be increased and the inner loop starts from j=1 again. We have 2*3 = 6 combinations.

Now lets raise that to a 3D-Problem. We need a third loop for that:

```
dim3_Matrix <- array(0,dim=c(2,3,4))

for (i in 1:2){
  for (j in 1:3){
    for (k in 1:4){
      dim3_Matrix[i,j,k] <- i*j*k
    }
  }
}
```

It runs the most inner loop 4times, increases the middle one, runs the 4 inner loops again...until we get 2*3*4 = 24 combinations in a 3D-Array.

I could continue like this with dim4, dim5 etc.
My problem now is that I want to keep the script variable. Sometimes I'll want to combine 2, sometimes 3, sometimes n-vectors. Suppose I know how many "layers" there are before the loops are run...how do I get a generalized form of this?

I am as far as this:

```
n_dimensions <- 3 # specify n° of dimensions
m_Elements <- c(2,3,4) # 2 elements in 1st dim, 3 in 2nd, 4 in 3rd

for (i in 1:n_dimensions){
  for (j in 1:m_Elements[i]){
    # ...
  }
}
```

But this will go like:

i1 j1 --> i1 j2

i2 j1 --> i2 j2 --> i2 j3

i3 j1 --> i3 j2 --> i3 j3 --> i3 j4

so this is 2 + 3 + 4 combinations instead of 2*3*4.

Please note: multiplying is only an example. Storing the results in a matrix/tensor is not the main problem. It's how to interlace the loops and to generalize it.

Thanks for reading through, I hope you get what I mean!

Comment: Take a look at `expand.grid()` - this might do something close to what you are after.

Comment: @Andrie  looks like that Led Zeppelin member ninja'd you :-)

Comment: It is, thank you, too!

Comment: This example (Java like pseudo code) show how to implement a variable depth nested for-loop: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406290/how-to-make-n-nested-for-loops-recursively/19406536#19406536

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
X<-list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)  #one entry for each dimension
Z<-expand.grid(X)
```

Z looks like:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    1    1
2     2    1    1
3     1    2    1
4     2    2    1
5     1    3    1
6     2    3    1
7     1    1    2
8     2    1    2
9     1    2    2
10    2    2    2 
11    1    3    2
12    2    3    2
13    1    1    3
14    2    1    3
15    1    2    3
16    2    2    3
17    1    3    3
18    2    3    3
19    1    1    4
20    2    1    4
21    1    2    4
22    2    2    4
23    1    3    4
24    2    3    4
```

So now  you have every combination in a `data.frame` and you can use apply functions or something similar to do what  you need to do. Such as:

```
apply(Z,1,prod)

 [1]  1  2  2  4  3  6  2  4  4  8  6 12  3  6  6 12  9 18  4  8  8 16 12 24
```

Comment: It's been a while, but - yeah! - expand.grid finally did the job! I had to have a look at lists in order to apply it to my script and run it correctly, but now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to:

`dim2_Matrix = outer(1:2, 1:3)`

`dim3_Matrix = outer(dim2_Matrix, 1:4)`

Which can be generalized to:

```
dim_n_Matrix <- function(n) {
  x <- 1:2
  if (n>1) {for (n in 2:n) {x <- outer(x, 1:(n+1))}} else {x <- matrix(1:2, nrow = 1)}
  return(x)
}
```